# Documenting enums using doxygen

Tags: html, enums, format, doxygen

The html documentation generated by doxygen for enums lists the enum to the left and the documentation to the right. However I need quite detailed documentation for each value and some of the names are very long thus making the right column with the documentation appear far out to the right and it looks very bad. Is there no possibility to make the documentation for each value appear below or above the value instead of to the right ?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Doxygen 1.7.5.1.  I had a similar situation...  I had a enumeration of about 1000 or so members that I was generating from a spreadsheet.  I wanted the integer value to be off to the right, with the Doxygen bit above the member.

All I did was use the triple slash above the member name.  For multi-line comments, I inserted a HTML line break where needed.  I only did the first verse, but I think it's fairly obvious.  Note: the first line breaks because of the period.  The subsequent lines do not.

```
///
/// \file test.h
/// \brief Test of Doxygen enum commenting.
///

//! A test of Doxygen commenting.
typedef enum _DOXYGEN_TEST
{

    /// This is a single line comment.
    Member_001,                            //  1

    /// This is a mutli-line comment.
    /// 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves       <br>
    /// Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;          <br>
    /// All mimsy were the borogoves,             <br>
    /// And the mome raths outgrabe.              <br>
    /// "Beware the Jabberwock, my son!           <br>
    /// The jaws that bite, the claws that catch! <br>
    /// Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun          <br>
    /// The frumious Bandersnatch!"
    /// 
    /// He took his vorpal sword in hand:
    /// Long time the manxome foe he sought--
    /// So rested he by the Tumtum tree,
    /// And stood awhile in thought.
    /// 
    /// And as in uffish thought he stood,
    /// The Jabberwock, with eyes of flame,
    /// Came whiffling through the tulgey wood,
    /// And burbled as it came!
    /// 
    /// One, two! One, two! and through and through
    /// The vorpal blade went snicker-snack!
    /// He left it dead, and with its head
    /// He went galumphing back.
    /// 
    /// "And hast thou slain the Jabberwock?
    /// Come to my arms, my beamish boy!
    /// O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!"
    /// He chortled in his joy.
    /// 
    /// 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
    /// Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
    /// All mimsy were the borogoves,
    /// And the mome raths outgrabe.
    Member_002,                            //  2

}
Doxygen_test;
```

The resulting Doxygen generated file:
[image: Doxygen generated doc for test.h]

Answer (score 0):

With doxygen 1.5.5, I didn't succeed in reproducing the behaviour you describes. I get an enum documentation similar to a param list documentation.

What I observe is consistent with the Doxygen documentation for [\enum command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdenum) and [its rendering](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/enum/html/class_enum___test.html).

Comment: Yes it's consistent, I just wonder if it can be changed because the default behavior does not work well in my situation. In the example rendering (the link that you provided) you can see that the documentation for the enum itself is on top while for the values the documentation is to the right.

Comment: I've tried again and, thanks to your comment, I now understand the problem. From the Doxygen example I've added a long V3V3V3... to AnotherEnum. The behaviour is exactly as you describe. Unfortunately I know no workaround.